# Android: Getting PERMISSION_DENIED on requesting Read and Write Permissions

Tags: java, android, file

I am new to Android development and currently working on an app that requires accessing JSON data from text files located in the device's "Documents" directory. To enable this functionality, I have added the necessary permissions for reading and writing files.

In my main activity, I have implemented the onCreate method where I request the required permissions from the user. However, during testing, I encountered an issue where I could only list the directories within the "Documents" directory, but not the actual files contained within them.

To investigate the problem, I implemented the onRequestPermissionsResult method and found that the grantResults array returned a value of -1, indicating that the permission request was denied (PERMISSION_DENIED).

I am currently working on resolving this issue to ensure that the app has proper access to both directories and files within the "Documents" directory.

Here's my code inside onCreate()

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    3);
        } else {
            tryFile();
        }
```

The function where I access the storage

```java
private void tryFile() {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), MyData");
        // /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyData/
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        Log.i("LOAD FILES:", directory.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i("FILE ACCESS: ", "no. of files: ".concat(String.valueOf(files.length)));

        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/MyData/test.txt");
        try {
            Log.i("LOAD FILES:", "file name: ". concat(file.getName()));
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            String fileContents = stringBuilder.toString();
            // Get the json object the retrieve the data            


        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The function onRequestPermissionsResult

```java
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 3) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                tryFile();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my manifest code

```xml
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="30"
        android:targetSdkVersion="32"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

Additionally, I made a peculiar observation while testing the app on my device(Android 13) using Android Studio. I created a new text file from my app in the directory where other files are present. Surprisingly, I could only see the newly created file and not the previously existing files within the directory. Strangely, when I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it through Android Studio, the file I had created in the previous session was no longer visible. This behavior raised further questions and prompted me to investigate the underlying cause.

Please guide me to what's the correct way to read all text files from a directory. I don't want to store the json data in the app private storage.

Comment: Android version of used device? Dont ask for usual READ and WRITE permissions on an Android 13 device. And if those files are not created by your app those permissions are useless and you have to use SAF.

Comment: @blackapps the Android version is 13.

Comment: @blackapps I tried using SAF with which I can select the directory using the file picker intent activity. I get the Uri like "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments%2MyData" but I cannot figure out how to open the list of files from the URI of the directory. I had tried to create a File obj from the uri but got an "invalid uri" error. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look at how permissions are requested. With the launch of Android 6.0 Marshmallow, Google introduced a new [runtime permission model](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), where users are not prompted for permissions during installation but rather when a program is running.You will still need the permissions declared in your Manifest file.

The following is an example of how you can achieve the same using Java.

1. Have a function to check if your App has the permissions you require.

```
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

2 Have a variable that holds the permissions you require.

```
   String[] PERMISSIONS = { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
```

3 In your onCreate function, you can invoke the function as follows.

```
     if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 1);
    }
```

I think this should work in your case, later on you can consider refactoring the code such that you can easily maintain/reuse.

Regards

Comment: I have declared the permissions in the manifest. I have implemented the function onRequestPermissionsResult which tells me that I got permission denied which I could not understand why.

Comment: Might you have followed what I posted, if not, please note that what you are doing will not work. Could it be that you never understood my explanation?

Comment: 1. First things first, you are requesting for the permissions ERRONEOUSLY   2. Whatever you do afterwards will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the permission issue but then I used ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent to solve my problem

```java
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
        // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker when it loads.
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

        startActivityForResult(intent, DOCUMENTS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DOCUMENTS_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {
                Uri directoryUri = data.getData();
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, directoryUri);
                assert directory != null;
                Log.i("directory files length", String.valueOf(directory.listFiles().length));
                for (DocumentFile documentFile : directory.listFiles()) {
                    Log.i("documentFile name ", documentFile.getName());
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(documentFile.getUri());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        // logic to read data

                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: First things first, the way you are requesting for permissions is wrong. Whatever you do afterwards will obviously not work.

Comment: Dont call directory.listFiles() twice as it is pretty slow.

Comment: @blackapps I will remove the log from my application code. It was just for debugging.